# How to implement 2 Result Sets from myBatis

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis

I'm working on a springboot app in which mybatis is calling a DB2 stored procedure and this stored procedure is returning 2 result sets:
and for each result set I defined a model(Fruit.java and Animal.java)

result set #1

| ID | NAME | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 2 |
| 2 | Orange | 3 |
| 3 | banana | 5 |

result set #2

| TYPE | NUM | LOC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| monkey | 2000 | London |
| dog | 3000 | New York |
| cat | 8000 | LA |

in MyMapper.java, what should my resultType be?

I have tried:

```
@Select(Value = "{call ....}) 
@Options(StatementType =    StatementType.CALLABLE) 
@Results({   
  @Result(property="id",  column="ID",    
  @Result(property="name", column="NAME",      
  @Result(property="qty", column="QTY" })
List<Fruit> getFruits(Map<String, String> params); 

@Select(Value = "{call ....})
@Options(StatementType = StatementType.CALLABLE)
@Results({
  @Result(property="type", column="TYPE", 
  @Result(property="num", column="NUM", 
  @Result(property="loc", column="LOC"
})
List<Animal> getAnimals(Map<String, String> params);
```

which didn't work, **I did get result set #1 ok this way** but not getting result set #2 (all fields from result set#2 came back null) .

I also tried:

```
 @Select(Value = "{call ....})
 @Options(StatementType = StatementType.CALLABLE)
 List<?> getResultSets(Map<String, String> params);
```

and:

```
  @Select(Value = "{call ....})
  @Options(StatementType = StatementType.CALLABLE)
  List<List<?>> getResultSets(Map<String, String> params);
```

For both I got "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException":

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.wrapper.CollectionWrapper.findProperty(CollectionWrapper.java:42)
    at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.MetaObject.findProperty(MetaObject.java:76)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.FastResultSetHandler.applyAutomaticMappings(FastResultSetHandler.java:342)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.FastResultSetHandler.getRowValue(FastResultSetHandler.java:267)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.FastResultSetHandler.handleRowValues(FastResultSetHandler.java:216)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.FastResultSetHandler.handleResultSet(FastResultSetHandler.java:188)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.FastResultSetHandler.handleResultSets(FastResultSetHandler.java:154)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.query(PreparedStatementHandler.java:57)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.query(RoutingStatementHandler.java:70)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.ReuseExecutor.doQuery(ReuseExecutor.java:54)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:259)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:132)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:105)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:81)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:104)
```

Google says it's because I should use a concrete type instead of generics.
**But the result sets are of different types: List of Fruit and List of Animal , what do I do?**

I'm using **all annotations** and no xml for mybatis.
in pom.xml I'm using mybatis-spring-boot-starter if that helps.

I have been stuck on this forever. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this with the following procedure.
It takes two IN parameters and returns the results for `fruit` first, then `animal`.
Let me know if you need me to make some adjustments.

```sql
create or replace procedure test_proc (
  in p1 varchar(20),
  in p2 varchar(20)
)
dynamic result sets 2
begin
  declare c1 cursor with return to caller for
  select * from animal;
  declare c2 cursor with return to caller for
  select * from fruit;
  open c2;
  open c1;
end
```

The Java mapper method would look as follows.
As you receive two result sets, you need to specify two result maps in `@ResultMap`.
Note that the order matters.

```java
@Select("{call test_proc(#{p1,mode=IN,jdbcType=VARCHAR},#{p2,mode=IN,jdbcType=VARCHAR})}")
@Options(statementType = StatementType.CALLABLE)
@ResultMap("fruitResultMap,animalResultMap")
List<List<?>> execProc(Map<String, String> params);
```

The returned list contains two lists. The first one is `List<Fruit>` and the second one is `List<Animal>`.

Now, to define those result maps without XML mapper, you need to declare extra methods.

```java
@Results(id = "fruitResultMap", value = {
  @Result(property = "id", column = "ID"),
  @Result(property = "name", column = "NAME"),
  @Result(property = "qty", column = "QTY")
})
@Select("select * from fruit")
List<Fruit> getFruits();

@Results(id = "animalResultMap", value = {
  @Result(property = "type", column = "TYPE"),
  @Result(property = "num", column = "NUM"),
  @Result(property = "loc", column = "LOC")
})
@Select("select * from animal")
List<Animal> getAnimals();
```

And here is an executable demo project:
https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-69145531

Comment: Thank you so much !!! You're a lifesaver! in my situation I replaced the table names with cursor names and Voila I got two result sets.